# How to change tintcolor to uiimage in cell loaded by sd_setImageWithURL?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, tintcolor

I'm loading a image into my UIImageView on my custom cells. This image is loaded using UIImageView+WebCache.h, and I want change the tintColor, but I'm trying this code but I can't change the color...

```
[cell.icon sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:myURL
            placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName options:SDWebImageRefreshCached];
   UIImage* img = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    cell.icon.image = [img imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
    cell.icon.tintColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be using `SDWebImage` function with completion block. Try this.

```
cell.icon.tintColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
[cell.icon sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:myURL] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName] options:SDWebImageRefreshCached completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {           
    cell.icon.image = [image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];            
}];
```

Answer (score 3):

> With Swift 5.0 You can use

```
cell.icon.tintColor = UIColor.yellow
cell.icon.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: myURL), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: imageName), options: SDWebImageRefreshCached, completed: { image, error, cacheType, imageURL in
    cell.icon.image = image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
})
```